# Duplicate table entry error

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

So I am just getting started with PHP/MySQL, and I have been having an issue when running the following code that attempts to insert data into a table. The error is being caused because I have the username column set to be unique and the username "TEST" has already been used. Is there a way that I could write an if statement to catch only the error that occurs when a duplicate entry is created?

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
            VALUES ('$_SESSION[username]', '$_SESSION[password]', '$_SESSION[email]')";
    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";}
    else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;}
```

The error I'm getting is:

Error: INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('TEST', 'password', 'example@gmail.com')
Duplicate entry 'TEST' for key 'username'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `INSERT IGNORE INTO users ... your query ...`. It will not create an error and after query you should check the value of `$con->affected_rows` - if it is equal to `0` then there was a duplicate (insert statement was failed and ignored).

Check it, I may be not correct, but as far as I remember, it should work.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to fix it. Thank you to others who posted answers too. Also, I just tested it, and it will actually show a 0 if the column already exists, not a -1.

Comment: Thank you. In the previous versions it was -1, according to notes at the end of the page http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 2):

MySQL returns an error in the form of a number, a state, and a message. Without parsing the message you will not be able to determine what column is duplicated.

Furthermore, MySQL will bomb on the first failure. So, if you have user_name and e_mail as duplicates, only the first duplicate encountered will be returned in the message.

EDIT: Here is the solution

To check for this specific error, you need to find the error code . It is `1062` for duplicate key. Then use the result from `errno()`  to compare with:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO ...');
if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    echo'no way!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you already have a row in there with that value. Please use prepared statements, nobody wants to suffer from hacked sites.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code there isn't a clear way to know which sql library you're using. Most have some sort of  error *code* that goes with the error *message*. If you can identify that you might have a shot.

Truthfully? Modify your query to deal with the duplicate name issue - or check for it before you create it.